# TYPO3 9.5 LTS Extension only returns default language for Database Entries

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-extensions

I am migrating an extension I wrote (started back for 6.2) to TYPO3 9.5.
I already had it running in 9.4.
Since I updated to LTS I can not get any translated values from the database.

The repository queries I am using are straight out of the extbase box (e.g. findByUid())

On the translated pages i get the desired results for standard content elements of TYPO3.

In the upgrade docs I found the "Important 82363" section, which says, that some changes have be done to localization but as far as I understand it, that only matters if using **languageOverlayMode** or **languageMode**. I don't use either of them. But setting the TypoScript switch

```
config.tx_extbase.features.consistentTranslationOverlayHandling = 0
```

gives me back my translations as they have been before 9.5.
But since this is only a temporary solution I need to find out, where my problem lies.

(Querying the querySettings gives me the results I expect; also the correct languageUid is displayed - but not used)

Thanks

Comment: Can you adds some info like the code of query and how the records are translated, so uid, l10n parent,...?

Comment: Hi @GeorgRinger, I use `$this->myRepository->findByUid(1)` in my Controller. All translations should be handled by extbase since I use all the default fields and nothing custom made (the extension was done with extensionbuilder long ago). Confusing part for me: findAll() gives me the correct language; using findAll() with outputting the result and *then* using findByUid() makes both have the correct translation! Same behaviour in a newly setup extensionbuilder extension. Thanks

Comment: And using findByUid() with outputing the result and then findAll() with output results in both having no translation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in TYPO3 extbase itself, see the issue https://forge.typo3.org/issues/86619 and the changes (which are not yet merged) at https://review.typo3.org/#/c/58635/.

Comment: Thanks for answering; I would have done it myself today, since I contributed in that forge topic and tested the patch this morning - all running fine with it.